# Checking panda dataframe column for a match in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns, a file id number and a list of keywords from that file. I essentially want to be able to iterate through each row and see if a chosen keyword is in the list of file key words and if it is print out the file id. Or I could make a new dataframe with all positive matches and print the file id's from there.
After researching it I was wanting to use 
`df.loc[df['key words'] == key_word, :]` 
which would give me a new dataframe of all the postive matches. The issue with this was that there were no positive matches as I forgot my 'key words' column has a list of key words in each row. Would anyone be able to help me find a solution? Much appreciated

EDIT: I'm unable to provide a snippet of my table as the data is sensitive, however this is the general idea of what it's like: 
[image]

Comment: i think you need `isin` but it would be more prudent if you read [mcve] and reproduce your issue/data and your target objective you'll get much better help this way.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be pandas inner join: You'd better first convert your key_word array to a pandas dataframe. let's say you have saved the array as "key_words.csv" and give the label of "my_key" to that:

```
col_name = ['my_key']
df1 = pd.read_csv("key_words.csv", names = col_name ,skiprows=[0],encoding ='utf-8')
```

use *skip_rows[0]* if your first line is comment if not ignore it.

**!!!Note that**: It is very important that both of your key_words encodings be exactly the same as they are string if not your code won't find any match**!!!**

To apply my comment you can do (sometimes it works without using convert_dtypes but some times not!):

```
df1[col_name] = df1[col_name].astype(str)
df1 = df1.convert_dtypes()
```

you need to repeat the same dtype converting for your df['key words'] column, too.

and you then can use inner join:

```
df12 = df1.merge(df, how ='inner', left_on = key1, right_on = key)
```

Key1 and Key being your labels of the columns you want to compare.
 df12 includes only the rows with a common keyword string, that you can save it in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the code right. I did:

```
for i in range(len(df['file id'])):
    if keyword in df.loc[i, 'key words']:
        print("https://www.website" + df.loc[i, 'file id'])
```

A bit easier than I thought. Thanks everyone for your answers though.